# Help with Forster distance conversion for FRET

Tags: units, fluorescence

For my project on Fluorescence, I'm trying to simplify the equation for the Forster distance (I obtained this from the Lakowicz book). To keep track, the units are in square brackets.

$$R_0 = \left(\frac{9000\kappa^2\Phi_D\ln(10)}{128\pi^5N_An^4}J(\lambda)\right)^{1/6} \approx 0.211 (\kappa^2n^{-4}\Phi_DJ(\lambda))^{1/6}\, [Å]$$
I'm using $J(\lambda)$ in units of $M^{-1}cm^{-1}nm^4$ but for some reason I can't seem to obtain the $0.211$ no matter how I do the conversion. I always seem to be off by a factor of $10^{-3}$, which I can't seem to locate.

For reference, $J(\lambda)$ is the overlap integral:
$$J(\lambda) = \frac{\int_0^{\infty} F_D(\lambda)\varepsilon_A(\lambda)\lambda^4 d\lambda}{\int_0^{\infty} F_D(\lambda) d\lambda}$$

For example, I simplified $R^6_0$, attempting to convert to Angstrom:

$$8.79\times10^{-25}\kappa^2\Phi_Dn^{-4} J(\lambda) [mol\,M^{-1}\,cm^{-1}\,nm^4]$$
$$=8.79\times10^{-25}\kappa^2\Phi_Dn^{-4} J(\lambda) [0.1m^210^{-36}m^4]$$
$$=R^6_0 = 8.79\times10^{-62}\kappa^2\Phi_Dn^{-4}J(\lambda) [m^6] = 8.79\times10^{-2} \kappa^2\Phi_Dn^{-4}J(\lambda)\,[Å]^6$$

Which, upon taking the 6th-root, I don't get the number $0.211$. If the power is $10^{-5}$ I do get the number.

What am I missing?
Any help appreciated. I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something painfully obvious, but I can't see it.

Cheers!

Comment: Might be of use - in [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.jpcc.8b04908) publication, there is a 9 where you have a 9000. Haven't worked through the rest and not sure if your expression is equivalent to their eq (2), p. 5, but might be a clue?

Comment: I did indeed wonder about that. I'm not 100% sure where the prefactor is derived, and most sources (including the lakowicz) appear to use 9000, and then have the 0.211 as well.

Comment: @FrankieS.Palmer, Your numbers seem to be right, a back of the envelope calculation also results in 0.0879, which is same as yours. However, other publications also use 9000. It has have a power 10^-5 in order to get 0.211. It means there is an extra hidden factor of 1000 in the numerator.

Comment: @M.Farooq Yeah, as mentioned before by Todd, if the numerator is simply a 9 then I get the right result- the issue is now more a case of why that's the case- as several sources (the Lakowicz book included) appear to give the 9000 as I have, but with the correct 0.211 result, too.

Comment: It has to be 9000, I checked several references, Lakowicz will not hopefully do this mistake of writing 9000 for 9. We are missing a 1000 factor somewhere.

Comment: It is probably in how the extinction coefficient is defined; usually as $dm^3/mol/cm$  as we use concentration in $mol/dm^3$ but may defined be as $m^3/mol/cm$ in some texts.

Comment: But the author, Lakowicz, after already clarified the units of the overlap integral.

Comment: what I meant was that as $\epsilon$ is in $dm^3/mol/cm$ but we work in SI then there is a factor of $10^{-5}$ in J .

Comment: Afaik, $M^{-1}cm^{-1} = 0.1m^2mol^{-1}$, which I've used

Answer (score 2):

A relevant discussion of the 9000-form vs 9-form can be found in section 3.4 of [Förster Resonance Energy Transfer-From theory to application](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=GXWAAQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PT8&ots=h8bmlWmoAU&sig=ckJP2RswSoS42okQZwWNjD9UExg#v=onepage&q&f=false) edited by Medintz and Hildebrandt and discussion in [Braslavsky, *et. al.*, 2008](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1039/b810620g).

I think the confusion might be stemming from how Förster used $N'$ to represent the number of particles per mole instead of $N_{A}$.

Both ($N'=\pu{6.02E20mmol^{-1}}$) and ($N_{A}=\pu{6.02E23mol^{-1}}$) represent equivalent numbers of particles per mole. But, it is improper to use $N_{A}$ with the 9000-form.

For example the first term should be $\frac{9ln(10)}{128\pi^{5}(6.02*10^{23})}$ which is $\pu{8.79E-22}$.

I think you may be inadvertently using $\frac{9000ln(10)}{128\pi^{5}(6.02*10^{23})}$ which is why you are getting $\pu{8.79E-25}$.

Otherwise I think you would need to correct your units by using:
$$\pu{8.79E-25}\kappa^{2}\Phi_{D}n^{-4}J(\lambda)[mol^{-3}M^{-1}cm^{-1}nm^{4}]$$

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // Use plain texts in CH SE titles. // For more, see [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I used the 9000 form due to the fact that that was what was given in my primary source (Principles of Fluorescence Spectroscopy, 3rd Ed. by J.R. Jakowicz) - In section 13.2 the formula is shown (equation 13.4), and in the text it's indicated that $N$ is just "Avogadro's Number"... Why would he have used the $\text{mmol}^{-1}$ version over the normal one?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure, I'll have to go back and re-read Lakowicz.